# Django Template: include another html template, but only once

Tags: python, django

How can I ensure that specific HTML files are not included multiple times in Django templates when passing metadata to different frontend frameworks?

I am working on a project where we use Django templates and need to pass metadata from Django to various JavaScript frontend frameworks (currently React, but potentially refactor to others in the future).

#### embed_data_foo.html

```
{{ foo_data|json_script:"foo_data" }}
```

#### some_page.html

```
{% include "embed_data_foo.html" %}
```

#### rendered

```html
<script id="foo_data" type="application/json">{"foo":"bar"}</script>
```

Our templates are designed compositionally and relatively small, which makes it easy to avoid accidental duplication. However, I want to have guardrails in place to prevent these specific files from being included multiple times. So doing this multiple times potentially, in extended templates, should still only result in the only one being placed.

#### some_page_but_with_whoopsies.html

```
{% include "embed_data_foo.html" %}
{% include "embed_data_foo.html" %}
{% include "embed_data_foo.html" %}
```

#### rendered

```html
<script id="foo_data" type="application/json">{"foo":"bar"}</script>
<script id="foo_data" type="application/json">{"foo":"bar"}</script>
<script id="foo_data" type="application/json">{"foo":"bar"}</script>
```

In the C programming language, I would achieve this using the `#ifndef`, `#define`, `#endif` pattern. Is there a similar approach or technique that I can use in Django templates to ensure that files are included only if they have not been included before?

Given that we will be onboarding many people in the near future, it's crucial for me to set them up for success and avoid any issues caused by duplicate imports.

What is the recommended approach to implement this in Django templates and ensure that specific HTML files are included only once?

Comment: why not make a preprocessing step that just greps for duplicate include lines? how do you handle something like `{% for i in ... %} {% include "some_template.html" %}{% end for %}`  which includes for each iteration of the loop but it is only 1 include directive ... what are you really trying to accomplish with this ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley perhaps that _is_ what I want, I don't know the full feature set of Django which is the impetus of the question. In this case, with duplicate the script tags, I'll have multiple `<script />` tags with the same `id` which isn't valid HTML. This is a naive example, but I have more complex scenarios that include details I've redacted into this simpler form. I was considering a custom tag as a solution, but the basic `includes` treats each rendered sub-template as discrete thus the child template doesn't affect the parent (EG: I can't signal recursively what has been included).

Comment: there is no recommended method i dont think ... as users regularly want to include multiple times for different inputs etc... honestly i would just make a CI job or git precommit hook that greps for duplicate includes and warns about them (or fails entirely depending on your desire)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-template-tags/). Create a `templatetags` directory in the same root as your `models.py` and `views.py`. In there, create a `custom_tags.py` and register a custom tag that will look at the list of currently included templates, and ignore the current template if it was already included:

```py
from django import template
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

register = template.Library()


@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def include_once(context, template_name):
    if 'included_templates' not in context.dicts[0]:
        context.dicts[0]['included_templates'] = set()

    if template_name not in context.dicts[0]['included_templates']:
        context.dicts[0]['included_templates'].add(template_name)
        return render_to_string(template_name, context.flatten())
    else:
        return ""
```

Now in your templates load your custom tags and use the new `include_once` tag:

```html
{% load custom_tags %}
{% include_once "embed_data_foo.html" %}
{% include_once "embed_data_foo.html" %}
{% include_once "embed_data_foo.html" %}
```

The only issue I can think with this is that it might use a lot of memory server-side if you have a large number of templates and/or high traffic.